# How to set current location manually in the map (sencha touch2)?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

**How can i set current location manually in the  map  (sencha touch 2), because proxy is not allowing me send my current location**

For instance:

...

```
items: [
  {
    xtype: 'map',
    longitude: 'X',
    latitude: 'Y'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following config option:

```
useCurrentLocation: true
```